Can the Hilbert space of identical particles be written as $L^2 (X)$ for some space $X$?
For $N$ distinguishable spinless particles in $d$ dimensions, we know that the Hilbert space their states belong to is $H_n = L^2 \left(\mathbb{R}^{d} \right) \otimes L^2 \left(\mathbb{R}^{d} \right) \otimes \cdots \otimes L^2 \left(\mathbb{R}^{d} \right)$, where the tensor product is performed $N$ times. If these are particles are instead identical, then we know that $N$ bosons correspond to the states in the symmetric part of $H_n$, while $N$ fermions correspond to the states in the antisymmetric part of $H_n$. Let us call the space of $N$ boson states $\Sigma (H_n)$ and the space of $N$ fermion states $\Lambda(H_n)$ respectively.
Now, it can be shown that $H_n$ is isomorphic to $L^2 \left(\mathbb{R}^{d N} \right)$. Can we extend this result for identical particles too? That is, can $\Sigma (H_n)$ and $\Lambda(H_n)$ be written as $L^2 \left(X \right)$ for some space $X$? If so, how would one prove this?

The question as written is meaningless, since all infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space are isomorphic as Hilbert spaces (proof: Pick a countable basis on both sides, map basis vector number k on one side to basis vector number k on the other). What is the notion of isomorphism used here for which this is not trivial?
